# Dynamic variable for angular ng-click attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the following way to use $scope variable ({{func}}() in this case) as function name in `ng-click`.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="{{func}}()">Call {{func}}</button></pre>
```

This works in angularjs-1.2.0rc3. See working plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/L0a99MhUUyBBaEyXO8Jx?p=preview)

Any future version from > 1.2.0rc3 throw this [error](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24parse/syntax?p0=func&p1=is)

What's changed? How can I use the above syntax in current angular version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok first of all **I do not recommend such a usage for ng-click** because angularjs itself do not support this, but if you still want to use it such a way here is your solution...

```
<button type="button" ng-click="$eval(functionName)()">...</button>
```

where

```
$scope.f1 = function() {
    ...
};
//name of function as a string
$scope.functionName = "f1";
```

this is what your are looking for and here is your [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/0zMNXkKuZ3Q3JGi25iI8?p=preview) example...

Comment: Got it. I guess converting to directive is the right way. Yes it's not a recommended way. But it used to work and it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

All I did was append scope to both variables

```
<form name="angular" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <button type="button" ng-click="{{scope.func}}()">
        Call {{func}}
    </button>
    <label>Status: {{scope.status}}</label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bebold/TmKLY/1/

I wouldn't advise going this route for dynamic variable change, a better choice would be to create a directive and do the binding within the template:

A great explanation can be found [HERE](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-expression-binding).

Comment: I don't think `scope` needs to be appended. Try replacing 1.2.0rc3 version with 1.2.1 or any other version and you will see the error in console.